# WPF Visual Studio Templates - extend tabitem

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, controls

I'm working on a wpf project in visual studio 2008. I would like to add a xmal and xaml.cs file that describe a TabItem. Templates exist for "Page", "UserControl" and others but not TabItem. How do I either make my own template or accomplish this without a template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating my own templates, I usually start from the Microsoft `ControlTemplate` examples.  Here is the [example ControlTemplate for TabItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752032.aspx).